# Is Alcohol consumption in units discrete or continuous?

Tags: continuous-data, discrete-data

Hi I’m really struggling to decide whether or not alcohol consumption in units is discrete or continuous data.

Would really appreciate any help thankyou.

Comment: ? Why does it matter?

Comment: Similar to @keith-b-halvorsen , it depends on how you plan on interpreting the final results ?

Comment: What units are you using?

Comment: Maybe if people consumed cubes of frozen alcohol you could view consumption as occurring in discrete amounts.  Even then, if most of your numbers were relatively large, it would still be effective to use continuous distributional models for analyses.  The ultimate question then is why should you care?

Comment: The operative consideration may be the time period or group over which you are measuring.  I mean, hopefully an individual person isn't drinking over 10 alcohol units per day.  But if you talking about the number units served by a restaurant in a day, that may easily be in the hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

A variable  X is continuous roughly/informally, if in order to plot the values X assumes, you do so without lifting your pen(cil) from the paper. If between any two values it assumes, there is always a third value in between. If you're plotting, e.g., number of children, you plot the possible values as 1,2,3,... n. There are no values between 1 and 2 . Then number of children is discrete. If you plot height ( say in inches), then , the values can be any number. Between, say, 69  and 70, you can find any other values: 69.1, 69.3, 69.40001.. , etc. Because height is a continuous variable.

Here, it would depend on how you measure consumption. Are you measuring it in terms of ounces, bottles, glasses, etc ? Say you're measuring in bottles. Would you consider fractional bottles, i.e., 1.5 bottles ?

Feel free to ask a followup.

Comment: Okay so the unit is ‘units’ so 1 unit of alcohol is equivalent to 10ml of alcohol on a beer can it says how many units there are so that could be 3.5 units. I’m using the data to see whether there is correlation between quantity of alcohol consumed a week by a person and there likelihood of participating in more or less than 4 hours of exercise a week. This confuses me because someone can drink say 3.18 Units but when asked most people report unit intake to the nearest 1.

Comment: Any comment on the downvote? I'm here to learn, but I cant read your mind, believe it or not.

Comment: Is participation in more than 4 hours binary? If it is, it won't work for standard OLS regression. Or are you using another approach?